# Fusion Table Layer Wizard shows search but not map

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I found several other people on here had the same issue with the Fusion Table Wizard generating HTML that works in the preview but when you try to embed the code on your own webpage pieces are missing. Mine for example, will show the search bar but not the map. Someone else had the same problem and it turned out that quotes were missing around the id number. But mine does have the appropriate quotes. So I'm wondering what is wrong with my code. I've compared my code to theirs several times looking for what is missing but can't figure it out.

Our webpage is hosted by jimdo, and I have to use the html/widget. I copy and paste the code into that. But it does say that some code requires you to edit the head section. That wouldn't be the problem would it? And if it is, what would I put in the head section and what would I put in the body section?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    var layer_1;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0817001045586, -89.74025),
        zoom: 6
      });
      var style = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: 11 }
          ]
        }
      ];
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col18",
          from: "1_rIjSmE6MLjWMF4JH-OIzHFcYCjKr-8eytn9v6Y"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 3
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col4",
          from: "1ZLOwVcCWsIA-1WNg_yICWjaRdWOTeVy9xpudaQ"
        },
        map: map
      });
    }
    function changeMap_0() {
      var whereClause;
      var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
      if (searchString != '--Select--') {
        whereClause = "'Counties' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
      }
      layer_0.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: "col18",
          from: "1_rIjSmE6MLjWMF4JH-OIzHFcYCjKr-8eytn9v6Y",
          where: whereClause
        }
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
        Counties
        <input type="text" id="search-string_0">
        <input type="button" onclick="changeMap_0()" value="Search">
      </label> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me, because I have been doing this for days now. And have finally decided to actually ask for help. Any input you have would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks, Angie

Comment: Your code as posted shows a map.  Try 1. loading the file on your local computer in a browser and seeing that it works.  2. Check for javascript errors on the hosted page. 3. Do a view:source in your browser on the hosted map, verify that it it the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this:

```
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
        Counties
        <input type="text" id="search-string_0">
        <input type="button" onclick="changeMap_0()" value="Search">
      </label> 
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    var layer_1;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0817001045586, -89.74025),
        zoom: 6
      });
      var style = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: 11 }
          ]
        }
      ];
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col18",
          from: "1_rIjSmE6MLjWMF4JH-OIzHFcYCjKr-8eytn9v6Y"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 3
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col4",
          from: "1ZLOwVcCWsIA-1WNg_yICWjaRdWOTeVy9xpudaQ"
        },
        map: map
      });
    }
    function changeMap_0() {
      var whereClause;
      var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
      if (searchString != '--Select--') {
        whereClause = "'Counties' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
      }
      layer_0.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: "col18",
          from: "1_rIjSmE6MLjWMF4JH-OIzHFcYCjKr-8eytn9v6Y",
          where: whereClause
        }
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

As it seems everything except the contents of `<body>` will be removed when you paste a complete HTML-source.

Comment: Sweet, thank you I will try those things and let you know how it goes. I appreciate your help! :)